# How to do incremental seed in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I'm asked to add a new role to existing live system developed in Laravel 5.2.  We already have `RoleSeeder`.  But if I add a new entry to `RoleSeeder`, I can't just run `php artisan db:seed --class=RoleSeeder` since it will try to recreate the other roles.  What is the expected way to incrementally add new record to seeder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup you cant just add new roles in your RoleSeeder coz when you re-run the RoleSeeder it will seed all the data,  so the solution is to create new seeder (RoleSeeder2) in your to seed new roles to your table

Comment: Any other way to do this without creating another seeder class? I'll have to maintain multiple seeders then.

Comment: currently nope, coz there's no tracking for what data are seeded and what data is not yet on the table.

so in short, you need to manage the seeders/seeding by yourself, that could be multiple seeders.

i feel you man, wew